# pfctl - howto add an anchor and make it active / load it

Tags: firewall, pfctl

So i can add an anchor to the already enabled firewall by doing something like this:

```
$ pfctl -a anchor_name -f /etc/anchor_rules.txt
```

the file "anchor_rules.txt" might contain something like this:

```
table <some-hosts> persist file /etc/someHostsToBlock.txt
block quick from any to some-hosts
```

Now, i can see the rules inside the anchor by doing this:

```
$ pfctl -a anchor_name -sr
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
block drop quick from any to some-hosts
```

**However**, when i show the current active ruleset with:

```
$ pfctl -sr
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*" all fragment reassemble
anchor "com.apple/*" all
```

i don't see the anchor called "**anchor_name**" which i just added. So the anchor is not actually active/loaded...

Why not, and how to load it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my understanding of *pf* your major anchor is missing. You may either use Apple's anchor(s) or a user defined anchor.

A user defined anchor is preferred:

1. Modify /private/etc/pf.conf:

   Add two lines to pf.conf like this:

   ```
   ...
   load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"

   #
   # usr.home anchor point
   #
   anchor "usr.home/*"
   load anchor "usr.home" from "/etc/pf.anchors/usr.home"
   ```
2. Create a file *usr.home*. In the example below I create an anchor SSH blocking SSH access from a local network to some IPs of the host:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/pf.anchors/usr.home
   ```

   and add

   ```
   #
   # usr.home ruleset, referred to by the modified /etc/pf.conf file.
   # See notes in that file regarding the anchor point in the main ruleset.
   #

   #
   # SSH anchor point.
   #

   anchor "SSH"
   load anchor "SSH" from "/etc/pf.rules/pfssh.rule"
   ```
3. Now create a new directory

   ```
   sudo mkdir /etc/pf.rules
   ```

   and the referenced file with:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/pf.rules/pfssh.rule
   ```

   and the following content:

   ```
   block in quick inet proto { tcp, udp } from 10.0.0.0/8 to { 10.128.8.145, 10.129.8.145 } port 22
   ```
4. Parse and test your pf.conf and your anchor file to make sure that they are error-free:

   ```
   sudo pfctl -vnf /etc/pf.conf
   sudo pfctl -vnf /etc/pf.anchors/usr.home
   ```
5. Reload pf:

   ```
   sudo pfctl -d
   sudo pfctl -e -f /etc/pf.conf
   ```

You can add additional anchors to your major usr.home anchor as demontrated in the major com.apple anchor.

You can also add additional dynamic sub-anchors with the following command (here I add a temporary block HTTP rule similar to the SSH rule - check the creation of a transitory sub-anchor: **usr.home/HTTP** here!):

```
echo "block drop in quick proto tcp from 10.0.0.0/8 to any port 80" | sudo pfctl -a usr.home/HTTP -f -
```

The temporary anchor doesn't survive a reboot!

One possible command to remove the temporary rule immediately is:

```
echo "" | sudo pfctl -a usr.home/HTTP -f -
```

---

A handy script to check all loaded anchors and rules is pfdump:

pfdump.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

function pfprint() {
  if [ -n "$1" ];then
    sudo pfctl -a "$2" -s"$1" 2>/dev/null
  else
    sudo pfctl -s"$1" 2>/dev/null
  fi
}

function print_all() {

  local p=$(printf "%-40s" $1)
  (
    pfprint r "$1" | sed "s,^,r     ,"
    pfprint n "$1" | sed "s,^,n     ,"
    pfprint A "$1" | sed "s,^,A     ,"
  ) | sed "s,^,$p,"

  for a in `pfprint A "$1"`; do
    print_all "$a"
  done
}

print_all
```

**All files mentioned require an empty new line at the end!**

Comment: something to be aware of... it seems pfdump.sh does NOT list the output / anchors in the ORDER they will be evaluated. So you could say it outputs things in the wrong order - which has effect on the result.

Comment: If you modify `/private/etc/pf.conf` directly will these changes survive across OS upgrades?

Comment: @Tom I’m not 100% certain, but I believe that merge-able changes to `/etc/pf.conf` will be preserved.  However, I can state with *certainty* that changes to `/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple`, will *not* be preserved.  Beware any guides or scripts that involve modifying that file.

Comment: @macserv aren't you supposed to create a user-level anchor and a launchd plist that tells pfctl to enable that anchor? this seems more maintainable than to edit system level files (altho I personally never got it to work with anchors..)

Answer (score 1):

Took me a while to find out how it seems to work without modifying system files. An official documentation how to properly use pf on macOS would be great, but I couldn't find any.

First, to show all anchors, you have to use `sudo pfctl -vsA`.

Your "anchor_rules.txt" seems to be wrong. I have placed mine under  "/etc/pf.anchors/block". At least under macOS 12.0.1 I have get erros with `sudo pfctl -vnf /etc/pf.anchors/block`. The working rules looks like the following. But I'm not sure, if it does what you think it does.

```
table <some-hosts> persist file "/etc/someHostsToBlock.txt"
block quick from any to <some-hosts>
```

To load the anchor and enable pf you have to use `sudo pfctl -a 'com.apple/block' -f /etc/pf.anchors/block -e`.

To start pf and load your custom anchor on system boot, you have to use launchd.

*/Library/LaunchDaemons/block.pfctl.plist*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>block.pfctl</string>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/var/run</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/sbin/pfctl</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>pfctl</string>
        <string>-a</string>
        <string>com.apple/block</string>
        <string>-f</string>
        <string>/etc/pf.anchors/block</string>
        <string>-e</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

`sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/block.pfctl.plist`