# Why can't I create new network connections after enabling PF with a simple custom ruleset using `pfctl -f`?

Tags: network, firewall, pfctl

> Why can't I create new network connections after enabling PF with a simple custom ruleset using `pfctl -f`?

I'm reading the official FAQ tutorial for OpenBSD's PF firewall, also used in macOS.

I've a single network interface `en0`, but after loading the my custom ruleset (`sudo pfctl -ef ~/pf.conf`), I cannot create new connections:

```
# block all traffic by default
block all

# allow outgoing traffic
pass out on en0 inet proto { tcp, udp } from any to any keep state
```

The loaded rules:

```
$ sudo pfctl -s rules
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
block drop all
pass out on en0 inet proto tcp all flags S/SA keep state
pass out on en0 inet proto udp all keep state
```

I know that `pass` rules imply `keep state`, so the target host will be able to answer and complete the TCP handshake.

Why doesn't it work?

Logs (as suggested by @dan):

```
11:38:57.252593 IP localhost.54219 > localhost.domain: 25416+ AAAA? tweak.dk. (26)
11:38:57.252653 IP localhost.64032 > localhost.domain: 49819+ A? tweak.dk. (26)
11:38:57.258578 IP localhost.57029 > localhost.domain: 60542+ AAAA? storage.tweak.dk. (34)
11:38:57.258636 IP localhost.63731 > localhost.domain: 1707+ A? storage.tweak.dk. (34)
11:38:57.378386 IP localhost.56727 > localhost.domain: 65417+ AAAA? clients1.google.com. (37)
11:38:57.378522 IP localhost.62210 > localhost.domain: 139+ A? clients1.google.com. (37)
11:38:57.443665 IP 192.168.0.2.34813 > broadcasthost.faximum: UDP, length 173
11:38:57.501016 IP localhost.62183 > localhost.domain: 11629+ AAAA? clients1.google.com. (37)
11:38:57.501147 IP localhost.53388 > localhost.domain: 42774+ A? clients1.google.com. (37)
11:38:57.511827 IP localhost.62420 > localhost.domain: 38225+ AAAA? clients1.google.com. (37)
11:38:57.511887 IP localhost.64524 > localhost.domain: 15042+ A? clients1.google.com. (37)
11:38:57.604447 IP localhost.59068 > localhost.domain: 13668+ AAAA? clients1.google.com. (37)
11:38:57.604519 IP localhost.51720 > localhost.domain: 55562+ A? clients1.google.com. (37)
11:38:57.693499 IP localhost.56993 > localhost.domain: 39058+ AAAA? init-p01st.push.apple.com. (43)
11:38:57.693545 IP localhost.57235 > localhost.domain: 27525+ A? init-p01st.push.apple.com. (43)
11:38:57.848208 IP localhost.61766 > localhost.domain: 22338+ AAAA? clients1.google.com. (37)
11:38:57.848280 IP localhost.54073 > localhost.domain: 33542+ A? clients1.google.com. (37)
11:38:58.037646 IP localhost.64422 > localhost.domain: 24380+ AAAA? clients1.google.com. (37)
11:38:58.037706 IP localhost.60153 > localhost.domain: 10848+ A? clients1.google.com. (37)
11:38:58.255389 IP localhost.54219 > localhost.domain: 25416+ AAAA? tweak.dk. (26)
11:38:58.255440 IP localhost.64032 > localhost.domain: 49819+ A? tweak.dk. (26)
11:38:58.259328 IP localhost.57029 > localhost.domain: 60542+ AAAA? storage.tweak.dk. (34)
11:38:58.259380 IP localhost.63731 > localhost.domain: 1707+ A? storage.tweak.dk. (34)
11:38:58.362581 IP localhost.63716 > localhost.domain: 6695+ AAAA? clients1.google.com. (37)
11:38:58.362662 IP localhost.57058 > localhost.domain: 1829+ A? clients1.google.com. (37)
11:38:58.457064 IP localhost.60834 > localhost.domain: 35607+ AAAA? clients1.google.com. (37)
11:38:58.457124 IP localhost.50331 > localhost.domain: 18857+ A? clients1.google.com. (37)
11:38:58.672209 IP 192.168.0.158 > 224.0.0.251: igmp v2 report 224.0.0.251
11:38:58.994741 IP localhost.57453 > localhost.domain: 12397+ AAAA? api-glb-bln.smoot.apple.com. (45)
11:38:58.994777 IP localhost.51068 > localhost.domain: 22480+ A? api-glb-bln.smoot.apple.com. (45)
11:38:59.030947 IP localhost.58518 > localhost.domain: 37923+ A? clients4.google.com. (37)
11:38:59.460793 IP localhost.60834 > localhost.domain: 35607+ AAAA? clients1.google.com. (37)
11:38:59.460846 IP localhost.50331 > localhost.domain: 18857+ A? clients1.google.com. (37)
11:39:00.258957 IP localhost.54219 > localhost.domain: 25416+ AAAA? tweak.dk. (26)
11:39:00.259010 IP localhost.64032 > localhost.domain: 49819+ A? tweak.dk. (26)
11:39:00.260138 IP localhost.57029 > localhost.domain: 60542+ AAAA? storage.tweak.dk. (34)
11:39:00.260199 IP localhost.63731 > localhost.domain: 1707+ A? storage.tweak.dk. (34)
11:39:00.413401 IP 192.168.0.2.34813 > broadcasthost.faximum: UDP, length 173
```

Answer (score 1):

### Debugging basics

To help you progress with PF, I advise you to create the special interface `pflog` with:

```
/usr/bin/sudo ifconfig pflog0 create
```

improve, for a short debugging time, your `pf.conf` with:

```
block log all
```

and next start to spy what is blocked with:

```
/usr/bin/sudo tcpdump -i pflog0
```

### Choice of IP protocols

Before trying to write your own rule set, decide if you want to use
IPv4, IPv6 or both and configure your network interface (`en0`) accordingly.
I wouldn't recommand to start with the last configuration which is already a nightmare to troubleshoot network problems (DNS, routing…).
(Concerning this "choice of IP protocols", beware of the cursed `Automatic` network configuration which does turn everything possible on so as
to be sure the dummies will always find a path to the Internet.)

As soon as you switch from IPv4 to IPv6, mind to change all your `pass...inet` rules into `pass...inet6` rules. Otherwise you will be in a perfect *cul de sac*.

### Debugging `pfctl`

Use the `pfdump.sh` from this top level answer on [pfctl - howto add an anchor and make it active / load it](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/312542/22003)

### Always keep a recovery path

2 more pieces of advice:

1. Always keep a backup of `/etc/pf.conf` so as to be able to restore a working state with:

   ```
   pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf
   ```
2. Always start your tests on a machine you have a physical access to (I mean not through `ssh` or `ARD`).

Comment: Thank you, Dan. Can it be that loading my rules disables Apple's anchors? What are they?

Comment: Also, can you see anything wrong with my rules by eye inspection? Shouldn't they be loaded with `-f`?

Comment: 1. Yes you removed the system anchors. They are defined within `/etc/pf.conf` . [return] 2. Yes: ARP is dropped by `block drop all`.

Comment: Ohh, I see. Do you know why it appears that the system anchors contain no rules? `sudo pfctl -a com.apple/200.AirDrop -sr` and `sudo pfctl -a com.apple/250.ApplicationFirewall -sr` both show no rules.

Comment: Also, `block all log` should be `block log all`. I don't believe this has to do with ARP. PF works on layer 3 and 4, and `arp` is not a supported `proto`? I've included logs. It seems that all DNS queries are on `localhost` - can you clarify :) ?

Comment: 2. Yes, thanks to your 1st debugging log I discovered that your `lo0` local interface is on IPv6. Your `pass...inet6` rules are missing. I improved my answer since this is a very common problem for users keeping the `Automatic` network configuration. Apple should have named it `Network for the dummies` :).

Comment: 4. Thank you. Fixed. Your DNS queries go through `localhost` as configured by the way Apple decided to route all name resolution through a local proxy which is the process `ps ax | egrep '[ /](PID|mDNS)'`.

Comment: Thank you - how do you see that `lo0` is on IPv6 from the logs?

Comment: Also, trying to redirect ports, I've come up with `rdr pass inet proto { tcp, udp } from localhost to localhost port 1234 -> localhost port 4444`. However, the command `nc localhost 1234` doesn't result in a connection to `nc -lvp 4444` - do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't allowed traffic on loopback meanwhile logs do show `localhost` is being used for resolving.

One way would be to use `set skip on lo0` but I'd advice using explicit

```
pass quick on lo0
```

instead (put in addition to your ruleset of course — somewhere in its very beginning).