# pf: Dynamically add rule to nat-anchor

Tags: vpn, firewall, internet-sharing, pfctl

I connect to a Cisco VPN Server and want to share that connection via wifi.

Using the macOS Internet Sharing feature, I can only select one interface to share - either my LAN adapter, or the VPN connection. Clients on the wifi can then only connect to either the iNet, or the VPN.

The VPN Server is only creating a split-tunnel connection - and switching to full tunnel is unfortunately not an option.

Setting my nat rules directly in `/etc/pf.conf/` works fine and solves my problem to a degree.

I want to script and dynamically add them using a `nat-anchor`. Setting the anchor with `load` for an external config works, however 
when I define my anchor in `pf.conf` and try to populate my rules using `pfctl` like so:

```
echo "                                                                                                                                      
nat on en8 from bridge100:network to any -> (en8)
nat on utun1 from bridge100:network to any -> (utun1)" | pfctl -a my.anchor -f -
```

or as a one-liner:

```
echo -e "nat on en8 from bridge100:network to any -> (en8)\nnat on utun1 from bridge100:network to any -> (utun1)\n" | pfctl -a my.anchor  -f -
```

(w/ or w/o the trailing `\n`)

I can confirm that the rules are set on my anchor using 
`pfctl -sn -a my.anchor` but the actual routing remains unchanged.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: too many text per logical unit

Comment: let me shorten it for you: How come adding a nat rule to an anchor using pfctl does not work on macOS?

Comment: Still not cleared up. It doesn't add or it does but w/o changing NAT policy?

Comment: rules add, but don't actually change the policy when using `pfctl`. Same goes for flushing rules using `pfctl -a my.anchor -F nat` i can confirm there are no more rules on the anchor using `pfctl -sn my.anchor` - however clients still reach the network.

Comment: Well, given it's stateful, only new connections should be failing after rules flush.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the top-level rules (the ones with empty anchor) do not have a reference to your nat-anchor. You need to make sure there is a nat rule with a "nat-anchor " in the TOP level rules linking to your anchor.

In general, for any rules to apply, you should be able to trace "nat-anchor" (or "WHATEVER-anchor") inclusion rules from the top level all the way to your anchor's config.

You can use 'pfctl -sn' to see the top-level nat rules. Should see a line like this:

```
nat-anchor "myanchor" all
```

For those with more deeply nested anchors, you can dump everything for all anchors using [this](https://gist.github.com/nwg/e5b41ae2736504dcf13fe600e117e824) script. The recursive printing mentioned in the man page has a bug and does not work (prints some stuff and 'DIOCGETRULES').

Anyway, just make sure each anchor from root to your rules has a `nat-anchor` directive, and it's either explicit, or if there are wildcard `*`s in the anchor string (was just `"myanchor"` here), then there is some intermediate or final anchor that matches the wildcard (wildcards match one level only).

Related answer here: [pfctl - howto add an anchor and make it active / load it](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/312400/pfctl-howto-add-an-anchor-and-make-it-active-load-it)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call `sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1` to enable packet forwarding.

You don't need to modify `/etc/pf.conf`.
It should be sufficient, if you change `-a my.anchor` to `-a 'com.apple/my.anchor'`.